# method for downloading each file for each button-android?

Tags: android, web, input, io, download

### method for downloading each file for each button-android

I have some button in my layout and want to download  different files with pressing each button
for first button i do not have problem it download the file (just when i determine full out put path it does not download example :Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/sound/cat.mp3" );
and secend problem is how to set method for secend button?
should i use like startDownload(); in first button?(i have different files!)

```
    package com.ahmado.testconnection;
    import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.URL;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.Dialog;
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Environment;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ImageView;


    public class Test extends Activity {
      public static final int DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS = 0;



    private Button          startBtn;

    private ProgressDialog  mProgressDialog;

    private String          URLDownload;

    private EditText        txtURL;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.test);

        // Permission StrictMode

        /*if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        }*/

        // btnDownload

        startBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDownload);

        startBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                startDownload();
               
                
            }

        });

    }



   

      private void startDownload() {

        // editText1
         ImageView IV=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        txtURL = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        
        URLDownload = txtURL.getText().toString();
       
        URLDownload = "http://uploadco.ir/uploads/k3f5im6vdhv31zfg6ry.jpg";
        /* if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONYCOMB) {

         }*/

        new DownloadFileAsync().execute(URLDownload);

    }



    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

        switch (id) {

            case DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS:

                mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

                mProgressDialog.setMessage("دانلود فایل...........");

                mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);

                mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);

                mProgressDialog.show();

                return mProgressDialog;

            default:

                return null;

        }

    }

   

     class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            super.onPreExecute();

            showDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);

        }



        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {

            int count;

            try {

                URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);

                HttpURLConnection conexion = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                conexion.connect();

                int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();

                Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Lenght of file: " + lenghtOfFile);

                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());

                // Get File Name from URL

                String fileName = URLDownload.substring(URLDownload.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, URLDownload.length());
                File k = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), "sending");
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(k);

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                long total = 0;

                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {

                    total += count;

                    publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));

                    output.write(data, 0, count);

                }
                Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "end download ");

                output.flush();

                output.close();

                input.close();

            }
            catch (Exception e) {}

            return null;

        }



        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {

            Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", progress[0]);

            mProgressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));

        }



        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {

            dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);

        }

    }


    }
```

Comment: `i do not have problem it download the file (just when i determine full out put path it does not download example` what do you mean? I don't understand. Does it save to file? Of course you can use more buttons and use the same asynctask. Determine File k before you start the task and pass as parameter.

Comment: i mean for second download which method should i use?

Comment: For first button use new DownloadFileAsync().execute(URLDownload1);. For second new DownloadFileAsync().execute(URLDownload2);. For third new DownloadFileAsync().execute(URLDownload3);. And so on. In async task replace "sending" by fileName.

Comment: If I replace "sending" by filename of urldownload2 then when I press first button it write secend file in sdcard?